# I can't get my overlay (for comments) to fill the proper width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My overlay currently looks like this and I'm looking for it to auto adjust based on the size (since this is responsive)...
[image]

Just to note... I am using Bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/

Here is the first set of html...

```
    <div class="Discussion box">
      <div class="topic">
        <img class="PhotoThumbnail TopicPhoto" src="{{user.profile.avatarURL}}" />
        <div class="Name">{{user.profile.firstName}} {{user.profile.lastName}} - {{title}}    </div>
        <p class="TopicText">{{body}}</p>
      </div>

      <div class="show-hide-comments">
        Show Comments (or Hide Comments if showing)
      </div>
      {{> postComments}}
    </div>
```

Here are is the code for comments & posts...

```
<template name="postComments">
     <div class="CommentOverlay">
    {{#each comments}}
    {{> showComment}}
    {{/each}}

    {{> newPostComment}}
    </div>
  </template>

  <template name="showComment">
    {{#if editing}}
    {{> editPostComment}}
    {{else}}
    <div class="TopicComments">
      <img class="PhotoThumbnail" src="{{user.profile.avatarURL}}" />
      <div class="Name">{{user.profile.firstName}} {{user.profile.lastName}}</div>
      <p class="CommentText">{{> editPencil}} {{body}}</p>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
  </template>

  <template name="newPostComment">
    <div class="TopicComments">
      <img class="PhotoThumbnail" src="{{currentUser.profile.avatarURL}}" />
      <textarea class="TopicAddCommentText" rows="2" name="comment" placeholder="Write a comment..."></textarea>
      <button data-action="post-comment" class="TopicAddCommentSubmit btn"><p class="SubmitButtonText">Submit</p></button>
    </div>
  </template>

  <template name="editPostComment">
    <div class="TopicComments">
      <img class="PhotoThumbnail" src="{{currentUser.profile.avatarURL}}" />
      <textarea class="TopicAddCommentText" rows="2" name="comment" placeholder="Write a comment..." autofocus>{{body}}</textarea>
      <button data-action="save-comment" class="TopicAddCommentSubmit btn"><p class="SubmitButtonText">Submit</p></button>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Here is the css...

```
/* Shared */
.PhotoThumbnail {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DEE2EC;
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

.bottom-border {
    border: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EEEEEE;
    margin: 0px -39px 0px -117px;
}

.TopicPhoto {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.Name {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -25px;
}

.CommentText{
    margin-left: -25px;
}

.EditComment {
    float: right;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}

.TopicText {
    min-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: -25px;
}

.TopicComments {
    min-height: 45px;
    padding: 0 0 0 80px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.TopicAddCommentText {
    border-color: #DEE2EC;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 85%;
    height: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.TopicAddCommentSubmit {
    width: 115px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #B679B4;
    border-color: #772A75;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    float: right;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #888888;
    margin: 0px -5px 0 0;
}

.SubmitButtonText {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 9px;
}

.CommentOverlay {
    background-color: #F6F7F8;
    margin-left: -37px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right: -38px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}



/* Discussions Only */

.Discussion {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DEE2EC;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.topic {
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 80px;
}







/* Goals Only */

.Goal {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DEE2EC;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.GoalBoxes {
    width: 49%;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    min-height: 110px;
    float: left;
}


.GoalTopRightBox {
    float: right;
}

.GoalBottomRightBox {
    float: right;
}

.GoalHeading {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5% -5%;
}

.GoalLine {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.GoalInput {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.goalposterline {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.show-hide-comments {
/*  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;*/
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  color: gray;
}
```

Comment: A JSfiddle would be useful.

Comment: Please post an example that reproduces the problem to jsfiddle.net and link it here so this question can be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without a demo of your code I can take a look at, but it looks like the root of your problems are the fact that the parent element `<div class="Discussion box">` has some `padding-left` applied.

```
.Discussion {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DEE2EC;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* padding-left: 30px; Remove this */
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

You should remove this and apply any padding to `<div class="topic">` instead.  Then you will need to apply the styles below to `<div class="CommentOverlay">`

```
.CommentOverlay {
    width: 100%; /* Add this */
    background-color: #F6F7F8;
    /* margin-left: -37px; Remove this */
    padding: 20px;
    /* margin-right: -38px; Remove this */
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hey pattle, I definitely appreciate the help. I made those modifications and took a photo of the results... This should hopefully make it clear as well. http://imgur.com/JQqXsLv

Comment: Aha after your comments... I found the error in my .box css.
That's what made all the difference. Thank you!